# Server Configuration Checklists

Tags: installation

I am looking for a check list of things that every person who is setting up a new server should be looking at. I am trying to create an internal process for our IT team and am looking for the basic main list of configuration when rolling out a new server. Anyone know of anything? (I am not looking for a 400 page microsoft document, just a simple complete checklist.)

Comment: Which do you want.  Simple or complete?  Seems to me that the two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: This is **hugely** environment-dependent - I'm afraid it's really something you need to develop on your own.  My checklist includes 5 items: Install FreeBSD. Enable SSH. Install radmind. Rack & stack box. Run deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can give you a checklist for *your* environment, but here are some basic items you need to make sure you take care of:

1. Hardware Test (if applicable, but at least make sure it matches what you bought)
2. Install the OS
3. Configure the OS. Pay special attention to:

   - Network configuration
   - Domain or other remote login service
   - Local user accounts
   - Necessary software for the server's role
   - OS Patches
4. Rack & Stack.  Make sure to verify:

   - Adequate power/cooling
   - Network connectivity
   - Adding the machine to any asset management system(s)
   - Adding the machine to any patch deployment system(s)
   - Adding the machine to any monitoring system(s)

Answer (score 2):

A simple checklist:

- "What does it have to do, and does it do it?"
- "If it goes wrong, do we have enough documented and backed up so we can fix it?"
- "Does everyone who needs to know about it, know about it?"

More detailed:

- Documentation of the setup and passwords
- Installed properly (i.e. all redundant cablework done, no bodges, etc.)
- Backed up
- Restores possible
- Added to your internal procedures for, e.g. warranty updates, OS updates, scheduled maintenance alerts
- Added to your monitoring platform
- Added to your hardware inventory system

"A server" is a bit too vague. What kind of server? What OS? What environment? For what purpose?

Comment: Keep a printed copy of all documentation. It will come in handy when servers are down or if its just a stressfull situation.

Comment: @artifex At least print enough documentation to recover your documentation system. Printing *everything* could get a bit out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't want a 400 page Microsoft document, what you *need* is a copy of "The Bible" -- *The Practice of System and Network Administration*, by Limoncelli et al.  It has whole chapters that help you identify what you need on your checklists.

Comment: This is the book i keep closest to my desk at all times.

Comment: Hell, I'm sitting on the couch at the moment and it's *still* within arm's reach.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to research puppet/chef recipes.  The only real way to get servers built correctly is to either automate the build or automate the policy enforcement.  A well documented puppet recipe will be both a good aid to someone in telling them how things are configured and provide a way to ensure that configuration is the way all servers are built.

More info on Chef:

http://wiki.opscode.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7274862

Puppet:

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html